# Ajax search not running on quotes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this php script that runs when someone enters text in a form and pressing submit. Problem is, when `'` och `"` is typed the script aren't running. I want it to search for that too.

The search script:

```
if(isset($_POST["name"]) === true && empty($_POST["name"]) === false) {

    $getFullName = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE (:name)");
    $getFullName->execute(array(":name" => "%" . $_POST["name"] . "%"));
    $results = $getFullName->fetchAll();

    $count = 0;

    foreach($results as $row):

        $count++;

        echo $row["name"];

    endforeach;

    if($count == 0){

        echo "Couldn't find anything.";

    }

    }
```

The jQuery:

```
$('input#name-submit').on('click', function() {


    var name = $('input#name').val();
    if ($(name) != '') {

        $.post('ajax/searchName.php', {name: name}, function(data) {

            $('div#name-data').text(data);

        });

    }


});
```

Thanks in advance!

Note that I also tried `htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]`) and `htmlentities($_POST["name"])`

Comment: May be addslashes($_POST["name"]) will help?

Comment: Use the `submit` event of the form instead of the `click` from the submit button. Then use the first passed parameter (the event object) to prevent the submit of the form `$("form").on("submit", function(ev){ ev.preventDefault(); // ajax goes here... });`

Answer (score 0):

You can encode each value using [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FencodeURIComponent), like this:

```
$('input#name-submit').on('click', function() {
    var name = $('input#name').val();
    if (name != '') {
        $.post('ajax/searchName.php', {"name": encodeURIComponent(name)}, function(data) {
            $('div#name-data').text(data);
        });
    }
});
```

You can also use [escape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.escape?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.escape)

```
escape(name)
```

Comment: If `data` isn't already a string ([see line 9552](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.3/jQuery.ajax)) jQuery calls [`jQuery.param()`](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.3/jQuery.param) which does the encoding for you

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"];
```

REFERENCE

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

ALSO CHANGE THIS

```
var name = $('input#name').val();
if (name != '') { // don't use $(name)
    $.post('ajax/searchName.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
        $('div#name-data').text(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I think it is something with the jQUery not passing the value to the function.

Comment: @JacobJohansson _I think..._ - Then check it ;) Either with a proxy like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) or on the server with something like `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: I did just now, it doesn't request anything from the server so it is only jQuery that is problem here. Is jQuery bugging because of ending quote?

Comment: @Jacob Johansson change what i have told and than try

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `base64_encode javascript` and decode you can use `base64_decode  PHP`

Base64_encode JavaScript code

```
function base64_encode (data) {
  // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
  // +   original by: Tyler Akins (http://rumkin.com)
  // +   improved by: Bayron Guevara
  // +   improved by: Thunder.m
  // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // +   bugfixed by: Pellentesque Malesuada
  // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // +   improved by: Rafał Kukawski (http://kukawski.pl)
  // *     example 1: base64_encode('Kevin van Zonneveld');
  // *     returns 1: 'S2V2aW4gdmFuIFpvbm5ldmVsZA=='
  // mozilla has this native
  // - but breaks in 2.0.0.12!
  //if (typeof this.window['btoa'] === 'function') {
  //    return btoa(data);
  //}
  var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
  var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
    ac = 0,
    enc = "",
    tmp_arr = [];

  if (!data) {
    return data;
  }

  do { // pack three octets into four hexets
    o1 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
    o2 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
    o3 = data.charCodeAt(i++);

    bits = o1 << 16 | o2 << 8 | o3;

    h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
    h2 = bits >> 12 & 0x3f;
    h3 = bits >> 6 & 0x3f;
    h4 = bits & 0x3f;

    // use hexets to index into b64, and append result to encoded string
    tmp_arr[ac++] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
  } while (i < data.length);

  enc = tmp_arr.join('');

  var r = data.length % 3;

  return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 3);

}
```

you just put this function and pass your name into this format

```
var encoded = base64_encode (name);
```

Then you just send this encoded variable into you ajax

on php page

```
<?php
$encodedname = $_POST['name'];
$name = base64_decode($encoded); //You got good result
?>
```